# LibGDX getting coordinates from TextureRegion drawn with a transformed projection matrix?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

Basically, my code is like so:

I have a an orthographic camera named cam, and a sprite batch named batch.

```
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(true, 136, gameHeight);

    batcher = new SpriteBatch();
    batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
```

What I want is to create a rectangle in an InputProcessor class that has the same x,y,width, and height as the texture region that was drawn with the sprite batch so I can touch detect that texture.

```
    batcher.draw(Rock, 30, 30, 80, 25);
```

But when I use "Rock.getTextureRegion.y" or "x" for the parameters of my Bounds rectangle, the bounds are very different.

Is it because the projectionMatrix is not present in that Input class? Do i need to create a viewport for that Input class?

Or is there anyway to assign the right coordinates ?

Answer (score 1):

The x, y, width and height parameters of a TextureRegion are its coordinates defining the region of the Texture it covers, so they have no relation whatsoever to where the TextureRegion is drawn on screen.

In fact, a TextureRegion object does not contain any data about where it is drawn. When you call `batch.draw(rock, ....)`, the batch is passing those coordinates to OpenGL, but it does not modify the TextureRegion object in any way.

What you should do is create a class that holds the parameters that are relevant to what you're doing. For example:

```
public class MyButton {
    public TextureRegion textureRegion;
    public float x, y, width, height;
}
```

Then you can set values for all its parameters and use those for both drawing with the batch and the input processor:

```
batch.draw(myButton.textureRegion, myButton.x, myButton.y, myButton.width, myButton.height);
```

There's a class included with LibGDX called Sprite that does track position and size, but I don't recommend using it because it is subclassed from TextureRegion, so it tends to lead towards poor object graph organization. (A TextureRegion is a graphical asset, but the position and size parameters are not.)

Comment: "Then you can set values for all its parameters and use those for both drawing with the batch and the input processor:"   If I use it for the input processor, wouldn't the coordinates be off? Do I have to convert the screen coordinates to the game world coordinates?

Comment: Yes, you always must do that when dealing with input coordinates. Use camera.unproject() on the screen coordinates to convert them to world coordinates.

Comment: Where would I put the camera.unproject() method? My project has a dedicated InputHandle class. The overall project is set up like the one in this link: http://www.kilobolt.com/day-12-completed-ui--source-code.html

Comment: It can go anywhere. I'm on my phone so can't look at the source to suggest the most logical place to put it. Whatever class holds the references to your button(s) should probably be responsible for responding to the input. So each time there is a touch down or drag, the InputHandler can report that to the other class, and the other class in turn unprojects and checks all the buttons for hits.

Comment: Nothing I'm trying is working. What should I put for the parameters? I have Stretch Viewport and an Orthrographic Camera cam. I set it up like so: cam.unproject(new Vector3(), viewport.getScreenX(),viewport.getScreenY(), viewport.getScreenWidth()/2,viewport.getScreenHeight()/2);

Comment: You shouldn't be dividing the Viewport width and height by 2. Since you are using Viewports, it's easier to just use Viewport.unproject(). Make sure your Viewport owns the camera you're using.

Comment: I think it's because I'm using the desktop launcher that it's not working. My viewport is 136 by 204, but the desktop launcher is 272 by 408. Is there anyway to get the coordinates to scale correctly? Do I have to do something like "(.80 * gameWidth, .80*gameHeight) for the x and y coordinates so that it works?

Comment: No, the whole point of Viewports is that it does all of the scaling for you. Desktop windows work the same as phone screens as far as how they report dimensions to the game.

Comment: Okay thanks. I should be more specific though. When I  specify an xy location to touch, around the bottom of the screen (like say, if gdx.input.x >5,  and gdx.input.y >170), which would be at the bottom of a 136x204 screen), for some reason  it goes to an area that's like half of it (so it would render at like 13, 85. If I type divide by two however, it registers perfectly - only on the desktop launcher however, not my phone. Sorry if this is difficult to understand, but do you know what this phenomenon is about?